# cant change the texture of a model

Tags: texturing, node-editor

sorry if this was asked before
i have not seen it.
feel free to link me
if it is somehwere here.

my problem is that suddenly i can not change a texture for one model anymore.
when i entered the file it was all pink. i had not moved any texture away.
it found all of them quickly. the one for the problematic mesh only after the
3rd time and now i am stuck with this. the texture is fine and applied as it
should be, but i can not change anything in texture paint mode. i cant even access it and this is what my nodes look like. 
that is not the name of the texture and i cant delete the node.
i am using cycles and the latest blender version.
anyone has a clue whats going on?

[image: undeleteable node]

Comment: Your material is a linked library, you have to make it local, then you have to make the texture datablock local too